# What's the easiest way to find all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tiny\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\2&\alpha\end{matrix}\right)$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is $$C:=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\2&\alpha\end{matrix}\right)$$ positive definite, positive semidefinite or indefinite?

It seems to be a simple task, but for some reason I can't figure out what the easiest way to complete it would be.

Clearly, $C$ would be positive definite iff $$x^TCx=x_1^2+4x_1x_2+\alpha x_2^2>0\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\{0\right\}$$
Now, we could distinguish several cases (such as $x_2\ne 0$, etc.), but that seems way too complicated to me.

Comment: The $2 \times 2$ case is easy enough, but for larger symmetric things you can always use Sylvester's criterion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: looking at the discriminant wont do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $x^TCx$ as a sum of squares:
$$x^TCx=(x_1+2x_2)^2-4x_2^2+\alpha x_2^2=(x_1+2x_2)^2+(\alpha-4)x_2^2.$$
Taking $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1+2x_2=0$, we derive that $\alpha \geqslant 4$ to be positive semi-definite; taking $x_1+2x_2=0$ and $x_2\neq 0$ shows that we need $\alpha\gt 4$ for $C$ to be positive definite. In these cases, the displayed equation shows that the converse is true.

To sum up: $C$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $\alpha\geqslant 4$; $C$ is positive definite if and only if $\alpha\geqslant 4$

Note that we could only argue with determinants since the dimension is $2$, but the method of the sum of square is more efficient in dimension $3$ or $4$.

Answer (score 3):

As the matrix is $2 \times 2$, you can just evaluate $\alpha$ in the cases: $\det(C) > 0$, $\det(C) \geq 0$, and $\det(C) < 0$, respectively.